# HTTP "Expires" header does not work in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http-headers, cache-control

My system is Windows 7 x64, Chrome 20.0.1132.57 m.

In my HTTP response header, I have:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=1000
Expires: *some date*
```

In IE & FF, the page is cached in local, and when I try to access again by typing the URL and hit enter, no request is send and the page is displayed correctly. But in Chrome, it always send a request to the server with the following header:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

I do not want the client send a request to my server and then reply 304. I want to save the round-trip time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Be carefull when you are testing. I noticed that in Chrome version 20 if I hit F5 to reload the page then in the network panel I see new requests.
Hoewer if I place the cursor to the title bar, after the current page url, and hit enter, I get resources from cache, whitch header was set to cache.

Also its better just use the max age. Max age and Expires is the same, but in max age you specify the duration.

See this:
http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-http-caching/
Method 3 and Method 4.

Comment: i am afraid this is not what i see. i tried to press enter in the navigation bar, but got the same result. i think chrome can guess the ip of the server, and if it is local host, it will always do the request...maybe google wants to make the developers happy...but they did not :(

Comment: even on this site, in crome when I inspect the network requests, I see that ga.js have the following response header: Expires:Tue, 14 Aug 2012 20:37:18 GMT. In case of F5 refresh it reloads, in case of enter in the nav bar it come from the cache

Comment: i think i figured out...if it a main request, initiated by user or by JS, Chrome will ignore max-age and enforce a request to be sent...hell

Comment: Thanks  @davidshen84! using internal links seem to work better for me. New tab behaviour is inconsistent

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem and I found out that if you make the request with a new chrome tab it will work.