# How to avoid a browser request using Expires

Tags: http-headers, cache-control

I'm writing a Java web service for training purposes on web optimisations. My web services send a response that expires in 365 days

```
@Path("cache2")
public class WsCache {
    @GET
        @Produces("application/json")
    public Response expires(){
        System.out.println("Expires in 365 days");
        String later = getDaysAfterHttpDate(365);
        return Response.ok("{Hello:hello}").header("Expires",later).build();
    }
}
```

The problem is that Chrome or Firefox makes it request using cache-control:

```
GET /fora-comments-ejb/api/cache2 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html...
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 ...
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;...
```

Because any value of `max-age` overrides `Expires`, is there a way to say firefox/Chrome not to use cache-control for the second request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As often, I found a bit later the [answer on Stack.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11849014/968988) You need a *real* link to cache, or the browser sends a max-cache=0, wich is - in my opinion - a good idea.

I just had to make an html file with the link :

```
<a href="fora-comments-ejb/api/cache">Fetch some JSON<a/>
```

and it works

[image]