# Why do Firefox and Chrome react differently to these HTTP headers?

Tags: google-chrome, http, etag, expires-header

I'm not sure if my question is based on a lack of understanding - or on Google Chrome working incorrect.

My server sends the following HTTP headers ([see yourself](http://cdn.umdiewelt.de/images/misc/c_logo_download.png)):

**Etag:"1031384541"

Expires:Mon, 03 Nov 2014 00:01:46 GMT**

On a reload Firefox will NOT ask the server but deliver a "200 OK" status code (that's how it should be).
**But Google Chrome insists on asking the server and then delivers a "304".**

Is there anything I did wrong? What should I change?

---

Btw.: Interestingly enough these are the default headers sent by GoGrid CDN - which I assume should be correct. But I'm also using the same approach on my own machine ([see yourself](http://www.umdiewelt.de/images/misc/c_logo_download.png)).

Comment: This seems like it could be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559599/http-expires-header-does-not-work-in-chrome  IE, a 'feature'

Comment: Yes, it's related, somehow... For me that doesn't seem to be a feature :-/ Also I found a site to test for correct headers and it looks good to me: https://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.umdiewelt.de%2Fimages%2Fmisc%2Fc_logo_download.png